# CSS text-transform: capitalize skips first word with back-to-back <span>'s unless white space.

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Odd issue with text-transform: capitalize and back-to-back span's in IE 11. It will not capitalize the first word without separating the spans with whitespace or whitespace before the span content. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<style>
 .upper { text-transform:capitalize; }
</style>
<body>

 <span>Broken:</span><span class="upper">john doe</span>
 <br>

 <span>Working:</span><span class="upper"> john doe</span>
 <br>

 <span>Working:</span>
 <span class="upper">john doe</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/57n67xpx/1/

For now I can wrap my spans in whitespace. A bug nonetheless...

Comment: so this happens only in IE 11?

Comment: Not an issue in Chrome. I haven't tested others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known interop issue](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Oct/0215.html). Implementations disagree on how `text-transform: capitalize` should behave with respect to punctuation. WebKit is notably the only one to capitalize a letter that immediately follows a punctuation mark without a space in between — everyone else behaves the same as IE. So it would seem that Safari and Chrome are the odd ones out, not IE.

If you absolutely require that a letter following a punctuation mark inline with no intermediate whitespace be capitalized, your best bet is making that element an inline-block. This causes the text in the element to become a separate run of text from the previous element, making the first letter of that element truly be its first letter for the purposes of `text-transform: capitalize`, but this will be a problem if your text can potentially wrap due to length.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my css I was wrapping a pair of spans in a div that was an inline-block element not each span.